# Prevent Natbib from inserting newline after \hbox immediately after \bibitem

Tags: natbib, indentation, box

If I use a `\hbox to \dimen` right after `\bibitem`, natbib seems to invoke a par break.Is there a way to avoid this or any other way to align the text after the em-dash with the other bibitems?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibhang=2em\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Herzer(1992)]{bib-01}Herzer, Manfred (1992), Magnus Hirschfeld. Leben und Werk eines jüdischen, schwulen und sozialistischen Sexologen, Frankfurt am Main.
\bibitem[Herzer(1997)]{bib-02}\hbox to \bibhang{---} (1997), Das Wissenschaftlich-humanitäre Komitee, in: Goodbye to Berlin --- 100 Jahre Schwulenbewegung, hg. v. Schwulen Museum/Akademie der Künste, Berlin, S.~83–87.Hewitt, Andrew (1996), Political Inversions. Homosexuality, Fascism, and the Modernist Imaginary, Stanford, CA.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of MWE run]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `\hbox`, TeX will append it to the current list being built.  If you are in horizontal mode (in a paragraph), TeX will append the `\hbox` to the horizontal list, making it a part of the current paragraph (that's what you want).  But if you are in vertical mode, then TeX will append that `\hbox` to the current vertical list, more or less like it does for a line in a paragraph (that's what you are doing), so it looks like as the `\hbox` stays in a paragraph of its own.

In plain TeX the solution would be to force the start of horizontal mode with `\leavevmode`, then you make sure TeX puts the `\hbox` in a horizontal list.  In LaTeX (you can use `\leavevmode` but) you should use `\makebox` instead:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibhang=2em\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Herzer(1992)]{bib-01}Herzer, Manfred (1992), Magnus Hirschfeld. Leben und Werk eines jüdischen, schwulen und sozialistischen Sexologen, Frankfurt am Main.
\bibitem[Herzer(1997)]{bib-02}\makebox[\bibhang][c]{---}(1997), Das Wissenschaftlich-humanitäre Komitee, in: Goodbye to Berlin --- 100 Jahre Schwulenbewegung, hg. v. Schwulen Museum/Akademie der Künste, Berlin, S.~83–87.Hewitt, Andrew (1996), Political Inversions. Homosexuality, Fascism, and the Modernist Imaginary, Stanford, CA.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason `\bibitem` "stays" in vertical mode? Wouldn't that mean that the page breaks for a bibitem are set *after*  bibitem itself is processed? Wouldn't that be leading to a false result when one refers to a `\bibitem` with `\pageref` and the text after the `\bibitem` is printed right after a page break?

Comment: @Lupino tex is always in vertical mode after an `\item`  (\bibitem is just the same) the paragraph is not started until the item text starts, when the label is inserted via everypar, So vertical mode material like `\hbox` does not force the item it start.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i did not know that, thanks. And to the second part of my question, about the evaluation of the item's id; am i understanding it correctly that the anchor for (page)refs is "set" with the expansion of that \everypar as well?

Comment: @Lupino yes well that's a hyperref thing (not actually used here) latex itself has no concept of a node to denote the target of a link (which is why hyperref is so complicated:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just saw that `\bibitem{xyz}` defines `\b@xyz` instead of `\r@xyz`, so `\pageref{xyz}` shouldn't work, anyways. Never mind my question :)